# Joomla 3: Advanced Options for modules not working

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

In Module Manager, when I go to the module settings, in the second tab called "Options" there is "Advanced Options" section. Inside Advanced Options, there are some fields such as `Module Tag`, `Header Tag` and `Header Class`. When I update these fields, I cannot see any update in the module's html. Do I need to call these functions in the module template using code something like this `$params->get('header_class')`? I thought this would work without having to make changes to the template code. Just wanted to clarify.

Comment: What are you developing? Are you writing a template? Does this happen with all modules in your template, or just with one of them? How do other templates do it?

Comment: I am experimenting with my new module.

I also tried with Joomla's `mod_articles_category` module and it seems to happen there too.

Comment: Btw, I am using Joomla's built-in Protostar template.

Comment: Please add some of the HTML around your module code, and what it should look like, and also please add the PHP line that includes the module position in the template.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are pointing to but this is what I have inside my module's `tmpl/default.php`: `<div class="<?php echo $params->get('header_class'); ?>"><?php echo $test; ?></div>`. Even `mod_articles_category` module does not have `$params->get('header_class')` statement inside its template. Was it left out intentionally?

Comment: Some options are supposed to do things on template level and some others on module level. I don't think the `header_class` and others should be called in your PHP.

Comment: Ok but I am not quite understanding what you are trying to say. Can you give me an example of how to get `header_class` to work on module level or template level? Thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38397/discussion-between-user1448031-and-mavrosxristoforos)

Comment: I think I saw an issue in the tracker where the header calls were not present in a few modules.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. If this is Joomla issue, then I don't wanna be spending too much time thinking about it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should reference those items via `$params`  such as $params->get('header_tag', 'h2') in the module chrome. If the module chrome does not make use of that parameter(s), then you won't see any change. You can create an override in your template /html/modules.php to use them.